# How to retrieve Model data in the Scaffold on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

It's been a week and I'm stuck at the same problem and I can't find a solution that fits my problem. I generated a Scaffold called Contracts (reason:string, paf:string...). Then I generated different tables using rails g model... models like Address, Person, Personal and others... all those tables Referenced to the Contracts Scaffold. I can actually render those fields in my _form.html.erb using `<%= f.text_field :city %>` (City is a string located in the Address model). Ok everything seems to work normally. But when I go to show.html.erb and do `<p><%=@contract.address.city%></p>` I get the noMethod error "Undefined method address" Then I tried `<p><%=@address.city%></p>` and I get noMethod error "undefined method city for nil:NilClass" I guess that is something on the controller, but I tried to add on the.

`def new @contract = Contract.new  @address = Address.new end`

I did the same on show controller

`def show @contract.find(params[id])@address.find(params[id] end`

(I'm not sure if the syntax is correct because I did a git reset and I don't remember exactly, the objective here it's just to show you guys what I tried. I know that is wrong)
But not success. I saw people generating various Scaffolds for multiple tables, but rails community says that is not a good practice.

Or maybe there is an easy way to generate different tables related to my scaffold?

I did the same project with all data in the same table but my boss asked to put in different tables.

```
  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "estado"
t.string "cidade"
t.string "bairro"
t.string "endereco"
t.string "cep"
t.bigint "contrato_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["contrato_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_contrato_id"

  create_table "contatos", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email"
t.string "phone"
t.bigint "contrato_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["contrato_id"], name: "index_contatos_on_contrato_id"


  create_table "contratos", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "razao"
t.string "cpnj"
t.string "insc_estadual"
t.string "insc_municipal"
t.string "paf"
t.string "empresa"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

  add_foreign_key "addresses", "contratos"
  add_foreign_key "contatos", "contratos"
  add_foreign_key "data", "contratos"
  add_foreign_key "responsavels", "contratos"
```

Contrato model

```
class Contrato < ApplicationRecord
   before_save do
    self.paf.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("paf")
   end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `schema.rb` file?

Comment: Please show you `Contract` model.

Comment: @SaraTibbetts I added part of my schema because it's huge, but the other tables are exactly the same.

Comment: @Yakov Related to the models there is nothing, the code there is for my checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the association on the Contract model:

```
class Contrato < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :address
   # etc..

   before_save do
    self.paf.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("paf")
   end
end
```

This is what actually creates the method in your model.

Check the guide for all the associations available:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Comment: Actually is the Address who belongs to the Contrato. When I generated the models I added references:contratos this automatically adds the "belongs_to" to the model.

Comment: @GabrielSavian But `Contrato` should know that it has address.

Comment: @Yakov If I remember correctly I tried this before. But I tried now and the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added association in **Contrato** model. If you want to get address from contrato like `@contrato.address.city`, you should add the assoication like below

```
class Contrato < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :address
   before_save do
    self.paf.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("paf")
   end
end
```

And for view city, make a little change in the syntax like `@contrato&.address&.city`

Also check the entries in `address` table that whether it contains the contract id for which you are checking the address present or not?

But, I want to know that you have generate a scaffold like  `rails generate scaffold contract field1 field2...`, then the generated modal should be `Contact` not contract .